# Preloading Ads in ExoPlayer with IMA Library for Android TV background Service without Decoder Conflicts

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am currently developing an Android Service that runs as a system application on Android TV in the background. I am using ExoPlayer with the IMA library to display ads as an overlay on top of other apps. I preload the ads and play them later, which works well most of the time. However, I occasionally encounter issues on some devices when the app underneath requests the decoder and I have an ad in cache. In these cases, the onPlayerError listener is called, forcing me to release the player.

I have tried various approaches, such as using different hardware and software decoders and video formats, but the issue persists. I have a couple of questions related to this problem:

- Is it possible to preload the ads by only downloading the file and
  preparing the codec only when I want to play the ad?
- Can i preload the ads, release the codec once they are loaded, and then reacquire
  the codec when I want to play the ads?

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you share more detail on what you mean by 'an ad you have in cache' and on the details of the error you see? ExoPlayer should support multiple concurrent players but as you say some devices may have limitations so it would help to see how that is manifesting itself.